# No best sellers on my magento

Tags: magento-1.9, reports, best-seller

I don't know why but my Magento store is not showing any best sellers. Isn't like that that a Magento store should show automatically all most sold products in the dashboard? I'm getting 0. And yes, I have sold for a few months now...

Anyone can give me clues/answers?

Comment: http://inchoo.net/magento/bestseller-products-in-magento/

Comment: Really?? Static?? :/ Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I work with the table Bestsellers to Show Bestsellers in Frontend like the class from inchoo... The table is by default empty - the Graph in backend to. If u make a Update for the Statistics then are Data available. Go in Backend to Reports > Update Reports, Select the one you want to see and chose the Action. Good Luck!